# How to call passportjs(node) API from Angular cli?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, angular-cli, passport.js

NodeJs configured and running fine with passportJS OAuth2, but the requirement is angular should call node api, both are runs in **different ports**, calling all nodeJS's rest API from angular and it runs fine using proxy.conf.json, while calling `/googleauth/redirect` from angular getting error response.

Response :

`Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code...` `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Google API Setting :

**Restrictions**

Authorised JavaScript origins :

```
http://localhost:4200
http://localhost:8088
```

Authorised redirect URIs :

```
http://localhost:4200/api/googleauth/redirect
http://localhost:8088/api/googleauth/redirect
```

Update 1 : CORS to app.js (new): but no changes.

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use('/api',cors(),require('./routes/api'));
```

Update 2 : api.js

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }));
```

passport setup

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const userModel = require('../model/user');

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
  done(null,user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id,done)=>{
  userModel.findById(id).then((user)=>{
    done(null,user);
  })
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    callbackURL:'/api/googleauth/redirect',
    clientID:'',
    clientSecret:''
  },(accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done) =>{
    console.log("call back function fired");
    //console.log(accessToken);
    userModel.findOne({email:profile.emails[0].value,authType:'google'},function(err,user){
        if(user){
          done(null,user);
        }else{
          done(null,user);
        }
    });
  }))
```

Comment: [This article might help](https://www.matthewtyler.io/handling-oauth2-with-node-js-and-angular-js-passport-to-the-rescue/)

Comment: Can you share the CORS configuration you are using in your nodejs REST API?

Comment: @QiongWu - added my cors config (updated my question)

Comment: @QiongWu - other api's are working fine, only passportjs oauth2 not runs.

Comment: ok, so from what I can see the issue is not with your nodejs cors, I think you are implementing the oauth redirect flow in the incorrect way. Is it possible that you are trying to directly open `/google` with $http.get? in this case angular will try to follow the redirect instead of changing the location of the browser to the google URL, causing the CORS error on the google URL. instead you need to make sure that the redirect causes a redirect on the browser

Comment: @QiongWu - I am not trying to open /google directly and its node router, angular does not tried to change url, also not opens out of the angular app too. If i hit url(http://localhost:4200/api/google) or (http://localhost:8088/api/google) works fine.

Comment: yes, I think what you need to do instead of $http.get is to use `window.location.href = 'localhost:8088/api/google';` in your angular app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164588/discussion-between-151291-and-qiong-wu).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem with a tutorial https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/how-to-handle-cors-in-an-angular2-and-node-express-applications-eb3de412abef

Only lack a detail... next to the lines 
import { BrowserXhr } from ‘@angular/http’; 
and 
import {CustExtBrowserXhr} from ‘./app/path-to-file/cust-ext-browser-xhr’; 
you should add 
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';